# Creating a word list using batch

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a batch file that prints out to a text file a list of combination of numbers and letters.
Using {`0`, ..., `9`, `a`, ..., `z`, `A`, ..., `Z`} as my character pool, I have 62 unique characters.
The word length starts as 1 and increases up to a predetermined value.

The script starts at `length = 1` and prints out `0` to `Z`.
Then it proceeds to `length = 2` and prints out `00` to `ZZ`, and so on...

Comment: Batch as in *nix or DOS?

Comment: Excuse me. If unit lenght is 1, do you want _all_ 1 chars from 0 to Z? Or just one random 1 char? If you are talking about _combinations_ in statistical sense, take into account that if unit lenght is large, the resulting combination may be huge!

Comment: This question sounds a lot like an attempt at brute-forcing a password :)

Comment: well it could not brute force one but it would compile a list that could be pluged into something like that. it also could be used for user name list because it is using a-z A-Z if you were to set the unit value to 8 but the amount of passwords or usernames created from having the value set to 8 would be well over 200 trillion combinations

Comment: btw thank you EitanT for the post fix makes more sense now i did spend 20 plus min trying to type out the first one but thank you again for the fix

Comment: like i said down below i tryed to plug what he gave me right into a batch file but it did not print the words out into the batch file any clue whats wrong?

Comment: could you give a example i am still new to this do you mean at the set permutation= point to set the value to 1 or making another loop with the goto statement refrenceing the makePermutation or am i way off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you want?

**TEST.BAT**

```
@echo off
set charPool=_0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
set charLen=62
(for /L %%a in (1,1,%1) do (
   set permutation=
   call :makePermutation %%a
)) > textfile.txt
goto :EOF

:makePermutation level
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set lastPermutation=%permutation%
for /L %%i in (1,1,%charLen%) do (
   set permutation=!lastPermutation!!charPool:~%%i,1!
   if %1 gtr 1 (
      set /A newLevel=%1-1
      call :makePermutation !newLevel!
   ) else (
      echo(!permutation!
   )
)
exit /B
```

The batch file must be started with a number as parameter which is the unit length.

For example on using `TEST.BAT 1` the text file `textfile.txt` contains 62 lines.

Note that `TEST.BAT 2` generates 3906 combinations (strictly speaking, *permutations* in statistical sense) from 0 to ZZ, and `TEST.BAT 3` generates 242234 combinations from 0 to ZZZ!

Calculation example for estimating the number of strings in text file (size of file):

Running `TEST.BAT` with `5` as parameter produces

```
62 ^ 5 + 62 ^ 4 + 62 ^ 3 + 62 ^ 2 + 62 ^ 1 = 931.151.402
```

strings in text file.

Comment: Well I tryed to plug in what you just gave me into a batch file. gave it a unit of 2. When I ran it, all it did was make the text file then stop and did not print the combinations not sure where I could add a pause in to see whats going on but the code it self looks right as to what I want. what i would like is to be able to set a unit for 8 but it starts at 1 and then works up to it. i do know that it would end up with well over 200 trillion combinations if the unit was set to 8. what would be amazing is if there was a way to right this to the ram on my computer and then at the end of

Comment: the process it would take whats stored in my ram and print it out into a text doc so that each time it incraments up it does not write out to a text file and thus increase the process time...

Comment: @Zebus Actually I tried it and it works. The only thing left is running this script in another loop from 1 to the desired length.

Comment: could you give a example i am still new to this do you mean at the set permutation=
point to set the value to 1....

Comment: I added a loop to cycle from unit lenght 1 up to the first parameter, and for each one generate the combinations _in the same text file_. This program "prints out to a text file" the result, as you requested. To see the result, wait that the program terminate and execute: `TYPE TEXTFILE.TXT`

Comment: Actually TEST 2 generates 3844+62 and TEST 3 generates 238328+3844+62 :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an iterative solution that is much faster.

No need for CALL.
Each permutation is only generated once.

I was able to generate up to length 4 with over 15 million permutations in less than 5 minutes.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set chars=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
set maxPos=61
del output.txt 2>nul

>prior.txt echo(""
for /l %%I in (1 1 %1) do (
  >new.txt (
    for /f %%A in (prior.txt) do for /l %%N in (0 1 %maxPos%) do echo(%%~A!chars:~%%N,1!
  )
  type new.txt>>output.txt
  move /y new.txt prior.txt >nul
)
del prior.txt
```