# Batch file to output random numbers and letters

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a batch file that will output to a text file a combination of numbers and letters, i found a good link to a post here of someone who can achieve this but i have two issues and they are, i don't understand it and that when i run it it doesn't work, can someone tell me what im doing wrong? also i wanted to add characters like @ in aswell?

thanks

[Creating a word list using batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037054/creating-a-word-list-using-batch)

Comment: Both batch files in the answers on referenced question work well, except the batch files are started without a number as parameter. They produce the text file with all possible combinations of the characters according to wanted maximum string length for usage in ? (brute force attacks?)

Comment: No it is not going to be used for brute force attacks, I am creating my own encryption method in C#. I won't go into details...

Answer (score 0):

This will create a line of random characters from the character set in the string inside it.

Launch it with a number after the batch file name - it will give you that many characters.

```
@echo off
if "%~1"=="" (
echo Run this batch file with a number after the name
echo It will put that number of random characters into the output.txt file
echo(
pause
goto :EOF
)

setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:: set the characters here - do not use ! in the set

set "chars=0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

:: count length of string
for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (
    '^(for %%i in ^("%chars%" .^) do @echo %%i^) ^| findstr /o .^| findstr /v /b 0') do set /a maxPos=%%~a-5-1


:: output the %1 number of random characters into the output.txt file
(
   for /l %%I in (1 1 %1) do (
      set /a rand=!random! %% %maxPos%
      call set /p "var=%%chars:~!rand!,1%%"<nul
   )
)>output.txt
```

Comment: Right ... Basically because I am plain stupid I want to confirm I reedit the batch file name for example Test.bat to Test1.Bat and this will work? Also what is the maximum I can go to? 5?

Comment: You can use any name but avoid names of system and batch commands.  It will work up to quite large numbers - how long does your string need to be?

Comment: Right I have added the script above to a batch file and have named it Start.bat I then renamed it to Start 10.bat as I wanted 10 for example for my encryption program upon running it I reach the part of the batch file where it says pause. And then it closes and no text file is generated, I even run it through cmd using the "path\Batchfile" 10 and this still did not work? Am I missing something really obvious, James

Comment: `start` is a batch file command, so try calling it `randomnum.bat`. The file is created in the current working directory so open a cmd prompt, change to the folder that the batch file is in and type `randomnum 10` and `output.txt` will be created in the same folder.

Comment: However i did want to ask; how do i get this to keep typing random names in the batch file as the encryption process will pick a random line and use that as the encryption recovery key, so this process is to generate a list of random numbers. if you get what i mean. i bet i have not explained myself very well but if you are confused i will elaborate after your next comment

Comment: Preferably to ensure tight security an infinite amount with no repeats, for example if you take 1 value it would be a-z-0 in one slot with no repeats ex 4 but if it was two values it would be a-z-0 with no repeats  ex A9. i kind of guessed you could loop the batch but it would generate posibilites that may have already generated is there a way to tell the batch that if the posibilities have been generated that they are not written in the file?

Answer (score -1):

```
echo off
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: "Set Alphanumeric=" you can define the Dictionary


set Alphanumeric=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

echo set length
set /p "Testlngth=>"
:Top_G_1

:: replace 62 with the amount of letters in the Dictionary

set /a Rnd=%random% %% 53-0
if %Rnd% gtr 53 goto Top_G_1


set Output=%Output%!Alphanumeric:~%Rnd%,1!

set /a Length=%length% +1

if %length% lss %Testlngth% goto Top_G_1

echo %Output%

pause
```

Comment: Kindly explain your answer - don't put just plain code there